# NGINX Forward HTTPS request to HTTP Backend Server and Back

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, reverse-proxy

On a single server instance, I have an NGINX web server that operates without any problems with the HTTPS and I have a backend server in Spring Boot running on port 8080. I do not want to open this port to the internet, therefore I would like to setup a reverse proxy with NGINX to forward the request that start with **/api** to my backend and return the response.

When I send request to the domain in the browser, my frontend application which runs in browser, sends some requests to my backend (starting with /api), my frontend uses the following base url:

```
http://my-ip:8080/api
```

And the nginx configuration is as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  ssl_certificate     /cert/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /cert/privkey.pem;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate     /cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /cert/privkey.pem;

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page 404 /index.html;
    location = / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      internal;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /api {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

I keep getting [Mixed Content Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) and my backend requests are being blocked by the browser since my Frontend uses http for the request.

If I try to use https in the Frontend URL, such as:
`https://my-ip:8080/api`

Then I get a different error:

```
GET https://my-ip/api/... net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

This is probably because my certificate is generated for my domain name and not for the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: In the frontend, we should send the request to https version and use the actual domain instead of the ip address because the domain name should match the domain of the certification.

The request: https://my-domain:8080/api

Then the nginx forwards this request properly.